# How to for loop in Tableau when you have a combined primary key

Tags: tableau-api, level-of-detail, tableau-desktop

Hi Everybody and thanks in advance to whom will answer my question:
I think I need a for loop in tableau and looking for a working around;

my table has the following structure

```
id, id_detail, result
1      1        fail
1      2        pass
1      3        pass
2      1        pass
2      2        pass
3      1        fail
3      2        pass
...
...
```

I need to assign to id=1 fail; id=2 pass; id=3 fail

[image: img]

do You have any suggestions?

Comment: could you please provide more context about the "logic" behind your need? Tableau doesn't have loops but maybe we can find a solution if you had more details.

Comment: I need to have the following logic at the product level: "if the product has at least one test with evaluation=fail then I want to record fail; pass result should be given to product only if all test evaluation are = pass;    Needed result for the following example is Product ID=1 Evaluation = Fail;  Product ID=2 Evaluation = Pass; Product ID=3 Evaluation = Fail:                                                                                                      
Product ID Test ID Test Evaluation
1 1 pass
1 2 pass
1 3 fail
2 1 pass
2 2 pass
3 1 pass
3 2 pass
3 3 pass
3 4 fail

Comment: that's what is like providing context for a better question in order to get better answer... let this method be your approach for the nex questions ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You may use the alphabetic order where `pass` is greater than `fail`

create this calculated field

```
{FIXED [Product ID]: MIN([Test Evaluation])}
```

and you'll get what you want

[image]